# Setting up naming rules for Web API model classes using Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

Good afternoon.
I have the following controller method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Метод создания вида работ
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">Название вида работ</param>
/// <param name="workUnitId">ИД единицы вида работ</param>
/// <returns>Результат создания вида работ</returns>
[Route(nameof(CreateWorkType))]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<DtoResult<DtoWorkType>>> CreateWorkType(string name, Guid? workUnitId = null)
{
     try
     {

          var result = await _workTypeService.CreateWorkType(name, workUnitId).ConfigureAwait(false);

          return Ok(result);
     }
     catch
     {
          return BadRequest($"Ошибка при выполнении создания вида работ с именем \"{name}\" и ИД единицы работ \"{workUnitId}\"");
     }
}
```

The method used is the generic class **DtoResult**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс результат
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип данных сущности</typeparam>
public class DtoResult<T> where T : class, new()
{
    #region Свойства

    /// <summary>
    /// Результат проверки сущности типа данных <see cref="T"/>
    /// </summary>
    public DtoValidationResult Validation { get; set; } = new DtoValidationResult();

    /// <summary>
    /// Данные сущности типа данных <see cref="T"/>
    /// </summary>
    public T Data { get; set; } = new T();

    #endregion
}
```

"Business" сlass **DtoWorkType**:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Класс вида работ
/// </summary>
public class DtoWorkType
{
    #region Свойства

    /// <summary>
    /// ИД вида работ
    /// </summary>
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Название вида работ
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Единица работ для вида работ
    /// </summary>
    public DtoWorkUnit WorkUnit { get; set; } = new DtoWorkUnit();

    #endregion
}
```

Using Swagger, a class named **DtoWorkTypeDtoResult** was automatically created.

[image]

**Question:**
Is it possible to use the SWAGGER configuration tools or other mechanisms to determine the name of the class, for example, using the following algorithm:

```
$"{nameof(T)}Result"
```

for the class to have the following name: **DtoWorkTypeResult**

not like now: **DtoWorkTypeDtoResult**

Comment: HI,@Anton, Do you custom the Swagger? In default Swagger, it will not  automatically create a class Name, Can you provide your swagger configuration in `startup or program(.Net6)` ? Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#customize-and-extend) about custom swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method **CustomSchemaIds** to configure the swagger:

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            //other code
            c.CustomSchemaIds(p => p.Name);

        });
```